# putExtra overriding other putExtra

Tags: android

In the for-loop below the last putExtra overrides the first putExtra even though they take different parameters and different vars.

First: putExtra(String,String)
Second: putExtra(String, int)

Note: videos[i] is a String array

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this,DownloadService.class);
        for(int i=0;i<videos.length;i++){
             intent.putExtra("VIDEOS",videos[i]);
         intent.putExtra("FILENR",(i + 1));          
             startService(intent);

        }
```

In my DownloadService which extends IntentService the value from VIDEOS is null !! 
Why is that ?

EDIT: 
This is the part of the code in my DownloadService class:

```
Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
    notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, null, 0);

notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, "Skitips", System.currentTimeMillis());
contentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.progress_layout);
notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
notification.contentView = contentView;
notification.contentIntent = contentIntent;
contentView.setProgressBar(R.id.status_progress, 100, 0, false);        
contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.status_text,"Downloading...");

String full_url = "";

    full_url = URL + intent.getStringExtra("VIDEOS");

String fileName = "";

    fileName = intent.getStringExtra("VIDEOS");

String fileNr = "";

    fileNr = intent.getStringExtra("FILENR");


    int count;






   Log.e("Whattttttt","is the value of VIDEOOOOSSSS: " + full_url);
    Log.e("Whatttt","is the value of fileNrrrrrrrrrrrr:" + fileNr);
    try {
    URL url = new URL(full_url);
    URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
    conexion.connect();
    File file = new File(root.getPath(), fileName);

    int lenghtOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();
    Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC", "Lenght of file: " + lenghtOfFile);

    InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
    OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file);

    byte data[] = new byte[1024];

    long total = 0;
```

contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.status_text,"Downloading (" + **fileNr** + "/77)");

in the bold text there fileNr i need to get the fileNr from the other activity but it's giving me null in this case...

Comment: look at my edited answer, I removed the for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Question the

key are always remain same for different values that's why,,

try to use

```
         intent.putExtra(DownloadService.VIDEOS+i,videos[i]);
         intent.putExtra(DownloadService.fileNr+i, i++);
```

and get result like,

```
        DownloadService.VIDEOS0,DownloadService.fileNr0,
        DownloadService.VIDEOS1,DownloadService.fileNr1,
```

EDIT: try this code..

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this,DownloadService.class);
        putStringArrayListExtra("Videos_key", videos);
        startService(intent);
```

And one more thing if you are passing `array of integer` and some `Array of video URI` then please try to use

```
    putStringArrayListExtra(String name, ArrayList<String> value)
    putIntegerArrayListExtra(String name, ArrayList<Integer> value)
```

and avoid loop..

Thanks.

Comment: I can't put the startService(intent) outside the for-loop, it won't allow me to download all the files... I understand now the point of sending a bundle with different keys put the problem now is how do i read them in the DownloadService class...

Comment: from, that you are starting so many services, right? If you are using the only one key just get that data by that key if your are using many keys like I mentioned above 0,1,.. then just create a loop and use same thing like array in key and get the values.

Comment: I don't quite understand this for-loop business in DownloadServices class. I think I need to read on how this putExtra thing works exactly.

Comment: @user967232 - dont use for loop, use the comment suggest code above.

Comment: I edited my question, provided some more information as to what my code looks like. If you can have a look !!!

Answer (score 4):

that's because putExtra() add data to an hashmap. With hashmap if you use the same key the previous value is overridden by the most recent.

Comment: But am I not using different keys?: VIDEOS and fileNr

Comment: those are string constants.. I assume you assing they different values. So yes, in your bundle you must have two values. One for videos and one for fileNr, but only one pair..

Comment: You are the one that are

Answer (score 0):

Well of course they overwrite each other, since you write them all with the same key (`DownloadService.VIDEOS` and `DownloadService.fileNr` are the same for all values).

You may add extra key like

```
intent.putExtra("number", videos.length);
```

outside your loop and then write values as

```
intent.putExtra(DownloadService.VIDEOS + i,videos[i]);
intent.putExtra(DownloadService.fileNr + i, i++);
```

And to read them read `number` first and use loop to read your values

Answer (score 0):

You are not giving different key name in your loop.Since you loop will be run more than once then next time you are puting the value videos[i] in previous key only in DownloadService.VIDEOS so try to give unique name for your key DownloadService.VIDEOS for second value and so on.Similary give unique name for DownloadService.fileNr when loop run more than once

Correct answer will be add i as a string in your key and then you get it by giving key name

putting the string value

> intent.putExtra(DownloadService.VIDEOS + i,videos[i]);
>
> intent.putExtra(DownloadService.fileNr +i, i++);

getting the string  value

```
 for(int i=0;i<videos.length;i++)
    {
    intent.getExtra(DownloadService.VIDEOS + i);
    }
```

Comment: I'm using this and I'm breaking the loop when the value is != "" or null but I just get the first file downloaded , it's like the other value are not being sent ...